# MySQL Pass an argument / value to a query

Tags: mysql, arguments

I am wondering if it is possible when running a MySQL select statement, that a user input is prompted.

Example: I want to find out the the total number of products sold and multiply it by (User input).

Is this possible in MySQL?

Thanks.

Comment: Someone asked the same as you before. You can check the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038269/how-can-i-use-a-user-input-variable-on-a-mysql-query)

Comment: thanks ealves I had a look at that but I wasn't sure if it was the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not within MySQL client (the normal client shipped with MySQL). You could write your own script to do it or with any luck find someone else who already has. But it's not built in.